# Discord ClientUser is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, constructor, jestjs, discord.js, client

i'm using discord.js with jest and i'm having this kind of problem

It accuses error in a piece of code that is in the modules, so I don't know if I can edit.

```
    ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

      at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports [as READY] (node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/READY.js:9:35)
      at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
      at WebSocketShard.onPacket (node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
      at WebSocketShard.onMessage (node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
      at WebSocket.onMessage (node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\READY.js:10
    const clientUser = new ClientUser(client, data.user);
                       ^

TypeError: ClientUser is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports [as READY] (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\READY.js:10:24)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:437:14)
    at Receiver.getData (E:\Projetos\thor\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:367:17)
```

Error is in:

```
module.exports = (client, { d: data }, shard) => {
  if (client.user) {
    client.user._patch(data.user);
  } else {
    if (!ClientUser) ClientUser = require('../../../structures/ClientUser');
    const clientUser = new ClientUser(client, data.user);
    client.user = clientUser;
    client.users.cache.set(clientUser.id, clientUser);
  }
```

that is from Discord.js itself so i don't know why it happens

Comment: Could you provide us with some code what you think might be causing this error?

Comment: `module.exports = (client, { d: data }, shard) => {
  if (client.user) {
    client.user._patch(data.user);
  } else {
    if (!ClientUser) ClientUser = require('../../../structures/ClientUser');
    const clientUser = new ClientUser(client, data.user);
    client.user = clientUser;
    client.users.cache.set(clientUser.id, clientUser);
  }`
i think is it

Comment: Can you share what's inside `structures/ClientUser`?